# while variable is not equal to x or y bash

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to get user input.
The input should be "1" or "2".
for some reason I keep getting prompt even when I type 1 or 2.

```
read -p "Your choice:  " UserChoice
            while [[ "$UserChoice" != "1" || "2" ]]
            do
                echo -e "\nInvalid choice please choose 1 or 2\n"
                read -p "Your choice:  " UserChoice
            done
```

I'll appreciate your help
Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`!=` does not distribute over `||`, which joins two *complete* expressions. Once that is fixed, you'll need to use `&&` instead of `||` as well.

```
while [[ "$UserChoice" != "1" && "$UserChoice" != "2" ]]
```

Actually, `bash` does support pattern matching which can be used similarly to what you had in mind.

```
while [[ $UserChoice != [12] ]]
```

With the `extglob` option set (which is on by default inside `[[ ... ]]` starting in bash 4.2, I believe), you can use something very close to what you originally had:

```
while [[ $UserChoice != @(1|2) ]]
```

Comment: No; the unquoted righthand side of the `!=` operator, inside `[[ ... ]]`, is treated as a pattern. Hm. Almost. (I mixed up regular patterns and extended patterns.)

Comment: Thanks Chepner, I used the your second offer, that worked perfectly. But I don't understand how it works cause the numbers are not separated. Why the BASH interpreter consider it as 1 and 2 and not as 12?